# How to specify the data types for JSON parsing?

Tags: crystal-lang

I have a JSON response which is an Array of Hash:

```
[{"project" => {"id" => 1, "name" => "Internal"},
 {"project" => {"id" => 2, "name" => "External"}}]
```

My code looks like this:

```
client = HTTP::Client.new(url, ssl: true)
response = client.get("/projects", ssl: true)
projects = JSON.parse(response.body) as Array
```

This gives me an Array but it seems I need to typecast the elements to actually use them otherwise I get `undefined method '[]' for Nil (compile-time type is (Nil | String | Int64 | Float64 | Bool | Hash(String, JSON::Type) | Array(JSON::Type)))`.

I tried `as Array(Hash)` but this gives me `can't use Hash(K, V) as generic type argument yet, use a more specific type`.

How do I specify the type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to cast these as you access the elements:

```
projects = JSON.parse(json).as(Array)
project = projects.first.as(Hash)["project"].as(Hash)
id = project["id"].as(Int64)
```

http://carc.in/#/r/f3f

But for well structured data like this you're better off with using `JSON.mapping`:

```
class ProjectContainer
  JSON.mapping({
    project: Project
  })
end

class Project
  JSON.mapping({
    id: Int64,
    name: String
  })
end

projects = Array(ProjectContainer).from_json(json)
project = projects.first.project
pp id = project.id
```

http://carc.in/#/r/f3g

You can see a slightly more detailed explanation of this problem at https://github.com/manastech/crystal/issues/982#issuecomment-121156428

Comment: You beat me for 1 minute!

Comment: appears the #as syntax has changed? https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/1uhw or you can use to_i and to_s FWIW.

Comment: According to this response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377857/how-to-configure-json-mapping-for-array-of-array-of-strings-to-become-a-hash/52389618#52389618 JSON.mapping is going to be removed in favor of JSON::Serializable

Answer (score 3):

You continue casting in every step:

```
projects = JSON.parse(response.body) as Array
projects.each do |project|
  project = project as Hash
  project = project["project"] as Hash
  id = project["id"] as Int
  name = project["name"] as String
end
```

But if your API response has a well-known structure, I strongly suggest you use JSON.mapping: https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.22.0/JSON.html#mapping-macro