# How to parse data from POST request

Tags: crystal-lang

I have a getter context : HTTP::Server::Context and a login form.
Now I want to parse data from context.request.body to get username and password which user input.

The response's content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I used HTTP::Params try to parse request.body but the result is nil.

Comment: You haven't told us the response's content type, but [here you can see how to parse a JSON response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32552291/641451).

Comment: @mgarciaisaia content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`HTTP::Params.parse`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.4/HTTP/Params.html#parse%28query%3AString%29%3Aself-class-method) is what you're looking for:

```
# Based on the sample code in https://crystal-lang.org/ home
require "http/server"

server = HTTP::Server.new(8080) do |context|
  context.response.content_type = "text/plain"
  if body = context.request.body
    params = HTTP::Params.parse(body)
    context.response.print "Hello #{params["user"]? || "Anonymous"}!"
  else
    context.response.print "You didn't POST any data :("
  end
end

puts "Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080"
server.listen
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually I using crouter for routing, but I try to use HTTP::Params to parse request.body and it generates error: no overload matches 'HTTP::Params.parse' with type.

But my mistake is crouter has already a params variable, to get body data, just use params["user"] like you did, don't need to parse data again.

Comment: Yeah - one would expect parsing those options is one of the things a framework would do for you. This is the "hands-on" approach - your framework would probably be calling this function. Glad it helped, anyways :)

Comment: Thanks mgarciaisaia, wish you a nice weekend :)